# Query about Name Server change of my domain?

Tags: dns, hosting

I want to change the nameserver of my live site. I am curious to know if, during the propagation, the site will not be live... or will it work fine?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to handle that if you just change your nameservers, without changing at the same time where your website is, which is this sequence of events:

1. Configure (Make your provider configure) your new nameservers with the exact same zone content as the one currently served. This may or may not need collaboration from current DNS provider.
2. Make sure everything works when using the new nameservers, you can do checks with online tools like https://zonemaster.net/ ; make sure not to use the default case, but use the one where you can provide specifically the nameservers to query (the new ones and not the current ones)
3. When everything is checked and double checked, then change your nameservers through your registrar
4. **BUT** make sure that the old DNS provider does not shut down DNS resolution for your domain on its nameservers immediately as the old nameserver may still get queries for some time (it depends on various TTLs, but typically 24 or 48 hours)
5. After the above delay has passed, the old nameservers can stop providing your zone as it will now be completely handled by the new nameservers.

Please note however that if your current zone is DNSSEC enabled doing the above will **break** the resolution, and you need far more extra steps to do the change safely (which should be another question and answer if needed).

Also note that there is no DNS "propagation" even if this concept is smeared all over. DNS is not a top down diffusion system, it is relying on caches and TTLs. Nameservers publishing records do it with some specific "Time To Live" (often 24 or 48 hours, sometimes more sometimes less depending on which records it is), period during which a cache is free to keep the value without doing a query. So in general results you get for DNS queries depend a lot on which recursive nameserver you used, if it is shared among different clients, and what is its current cache content, which depend on all (recent) past queries to it for the same zone/records.